# Truncate flex child in landscape or force to be on its own line if portrait

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I am using CSS (here via Tailwind for brevity) to force a flex child to be on its own line in portrait mode by making the flex container `flex-wrap` and changing the child's `order` to last and width to full so that it has to go on its own line.

```html
<div class="flex gap-2 flex-wrap [&_*]:border-b [&_*]:px-2">
  <div>fixed</div>
  <div class="truncate order-last w-full landscape:order-[unset] landscape:w-[unset]">variable</div>
  <div class="flex-1 text-center">stretch</div>
  <div>fixed</div>
</div>
```

This works perfectly fine.

Portrait:

[image]

Landscape:

[image]

It breaks down when the `truncate` child has content which was supposed to get truncated but in reality ends up pushing out the other children to a new line because of `flex-wrap`. Works on portrait, but in landscape, the `truncate` child just keeps going and pushes out its siblings over the edge.

Portrait:

[image]

Landscape:

[image]

This is the desired result:

Portrait:

[image]

Landscape:

[image]

What CSS options do I have to control the order in which `flex-wrap` and `text-overflow: ellipsis` kick in such that the text in the `truncate` child ellipsizes instead of pushing its siblings out of the way onto the next line?

[Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/gWPtR9nMdW?size=410x350)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following styles to truncate solve the problem

```
.truncate {
    flex-basis: 10px;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

I don't know tailwind, so i can give you only the solution in plain CSS

Comment: Awesome! I had to made `flex-basis` conditional to only apply in landscape mode otherwise it would never pop on its own line in portrait, but with this change this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation) media query, or specify a point in the media query when you want the `.truncate` to break to a new line.
A simple example that does what you want (if I understand the question correctly...):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 320px;
}

.wrapp{
  padding: 16px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 16px;
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  .wrapp{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}

.fixed {
  flex: none;
}

.truncate {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  .truncate {
    order: 1;
  }
}

.stretch {
  margin: auto;
  flex: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapp">
  <div class="fixed">fixed</div>
  <div class="truncate">
    variable variable variable variable variable variable variable variable variable
  </div>
  <div class="stretch">stretch</div>
  <div class="fixed">fixed</div>
</div>
```